# Why Salesforce does not accept my REGEX?

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule, regular-expressions, long-text-area

I have a RegEx created and tested in regex platforms, this one:

```
;.+$
```

If I check its functionality the result is okay, you could check it too in this link https://regex101.com/r/ocDofm/1/.

The problem is that, when I implement it into a Validation Rule for a Specific field, it does not work. My Validation Rule is :

```
REGEX( Email__c, ';.+$')
```

And, if I put the same text that I use on regex101.com web, the Validation Rule does not run. For example, if I open Email__c field, which is a Long Text Area field, and I put this text;

*test@test.com;test2@test.com;and so on...*

Validation Rule should work and error message should appear, but it happens nothing.

Any idea? Thanks.

EDIT: There is an example of the text that I want to be possible in the Email__c field:

```
john@gmail.com;
anne@gmail.com;
lewis@gmail.com;
```

So, the next text, should fire the Validation Rule:

```
john@gmail.com;a
anne@gmail.com;
lewis@gmail.com;
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect the validation rule to allow and disallow?

Comment: It must avoid that user put so many emails inline. So, the rule is that user must put emails ending with ';' and with line breaks, he cannot put characters after the ';' character in the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because SFDC matches the whole field against your REGEX, your whole Email__c is not only ';.+$', plus `$` is a special character, so you need something like this

`REGEX( Email__c, '.*[;.+$].*')`

If you're only interested in `;` character then put it like this `'.*;.*'`

Another point is that if you are only curious about `;` character you can use `CONTAINS(Email__c, ';')`

**UPDATE:**

Try this one `.*;[^\n].*`, this should only trigger when you don't have new line after ;

**UPDATE2:**

`REGEX( Email__c, '((.||(\r?\n))*;.((\r?\n)||$)(.||(\r?\n))*)')`

Comment: I appreciate your help, and it's useful understand more about regex and validationrules, but still not working...

Comment: Emails must end with ";" character, and be listed with line breaks.

Example:

john@gmail.com;(line break)
anne@gmail.com;(line break)
lewis@gmail.com;

Comment: so if you have line break it's ok, if you don't have line break it's an error?

Comment: I just tested without line breaks and my Regex works, I'll update it for line breaks right now

Comment: Sorry, I put the example on my question text, because here in this comments I could not put properly.

Comment: updated the answer, updated REGEX is after **UPDATE:**

Comment: I'm using https://www.regextester.com/ usually)

Comment: Still not working... :/ I mean, your code and the code I used before works in a RegEx editor, but not in Salesforce, that's the problem.

Comment: ye, checked it with Custom Field and it actually doesn't work, really weird, give me a few minutes, I'll figure it out, it's either a bug or incorrect new lines

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: added update 2, tested with your examples

Comment: it doesn't check for the line ending with ';' though

Comment: Well... It's okay, it covers the options that I wanted to. Thank you so much! You're superb! How did you get the solution?

Comment: Please mark it as an answer if it solves your problem)

Comment: I played a lot in Regex debugger, the main issue I had is that it was finding place where `;a` exists, but wasn't fully covering other parts of the string